# El Tiempo máximo de 30 segundos se ha excedido

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, excepciones, try-catch

Tengo un error:

> **FatalErrorException in HandleExceptions.php line 58:
>   Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este es el error
En Laravel 5. Sé que es un problema de PHP y sé como extenderlo a más tiempo, pero **me gustaría personalizar este mensaje** y mostrarlo en mi vista, trato de obtener la excepción con un `try-catch` pero aun así el mensaje sigue saliendo como la imagen.

**Éste es mi código**:

```
public function employerZklib(Request $request){
    try{
    $id=$request->get('biome');
    $biometric=Biometric::find($id);
    $connect= new zklib($biometric->ip,$biometric->port);
        if($connect->connect()){
            $users = $connect->getUser();
            $connect->disconnect();
            $employers=Employer::EmployersForItUser();
            return view('employer.biometrics',compact('users','employers','biometric'));
        }else{
            $users = [];
            $employers=Employer::EmployersForItUser();
            return view('employer.biometrics',compact('users','employers','biometric'));
        }
    }catch (\Exception $e){
        Session::flash("error",$e->getMessage());
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

La parte donde hago `$connect= new zklib($biometric->ip,$biometric->port);` (esto es una conexión de un socket) es donde me sale la excepción, *esto es algo normal*, ya que si existe alguna desconexión de internet este buscara el socket hasta llegar al límite de tiempo.

> Así que básicamente la pregunta es: ¿cómo capturo esta excepción?

Comment: Creo que deberías configurar el tiempo de timeout del socket para que sea inferior al tiempo máximo de ejecución de PHP, de modo que genere un error o excepción que puedas interceptar en tu código. Hacerlo a través del gestor de excepciones del framework es matar moscas a cañonazos. He editado mi respuesta para indicarte cómo modificar el timeout (60 segundos por defecto, tal y como indico en mi enlace al código fuente original).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## ¿Cómo capturo esta excepción?

**No puedes capturarlo con un bloque `try / catch`.**

No se trata de una excepción como las que pueden lanzarse con [`throw`](http://php.net/throw), si no un error como los que pueden generarse con [`trigger_error`](http://php.net/trigger-error).

No se puede capturar un error generado como medida de defensa contra errores de programación que consuman recursos de manera indefinida (como bucles infinitos), contra [ataques DoS (Denial of Service)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_de_denegaci%C3%B3n_de_servicio), etc.

## Solución propuesta

En tu caso, y [basado en el código fuente de `zklib`](https://github.com/dnaextrim/php_zklib/blob/master/zklib/zklib.php#L18):

```
/* Reducimos el timeout a 10 segundos */
socket_set_option(
  $connect->zkclient,
  SOL_SOCKET,
  SO_RCVTIMEO,
  [
    'sec' => 10,
    'usec' => 0,
  ]
);
```

## Otras soluciones

Se puede matar la mosca a cañonazos interceptando el evento [`shutdown`](http://php.net/register_shutdown_function) que [es como lo hace el framework symfony](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ErrorHandler.php#L116) en el que se basa Laravel.

La página de error que ves [se monta en `ExceptionHandler.php`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/9295a4f1eba9ed9050c7aba634bf1b15ef649b65/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ExceptionHandler.php#L210).

Gracias al cual Laravel [convierte el error en excepción](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php#L45):

```
public function handleError($level, $message, $file = '', $line = 0, $context = [])
{
    if (error_reporting() & $level) {
        throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $level, $file, $line);
    }
}
```

Este tipo de "trucos", como he dicho, son para matar moscas a cañonazos. Debes averiguar el motivo por el que tu script consume más de 30 segundos en ejecutarse y por lo tanto genera ese error (y no [excepción](http://php.net/exceptions)) y arreglar el problema en su raíz, no su efecto.

[En la documentación](http://php.net/set-time-limit) puede leerse que en sistemas UN*X (Linux, AIX, BSD, etc) el tiempo de ejecución es el tiempo de uso de CPU sin contar llamadas al sistema para abrir archivos, realizar consultas SQL, llamar a APIs REST externas, etc... sin embargo esto no es así en sistemas operativos Windows:

> **Nota:** La función `set_time_limit()` y la directiva de configuración
>   `max_execution_time` sólo afectan el tiempo de ejecución del script
>   mismo. Todo el tiempo dedicado a la actividad que ocurre fuera de la
>   ejecución del script, como las llamadas al sistema usando `system()`,
>   operaciones de secuencia, consultas a la bases de datos, etc. No se
>   incluyen cuando se determina el tiempo máximo del script en
>   funcionamiento. Esto no es cierto en Windows, donde el tiempo medido
>   es real.

En todos los sistemas operativos la llamada a `set_time_limit()` reinicia el contador de tiempo, por lo que puedes llamarla previamente a cada llamada a un API externo en Windows para aumentar el tiempo y que no se acumule el tiempo de cada llamada independiente.

También puedes configurar un tiempo máximo de ejecución para cada consulta que sepas que es susceptible de durar más tiempo del necesario y capturar el error devuelto cuando este tiempo se supere **antes de que se genere este error**, por ejemplo:

- Curl: opciones `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT`, `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` usando [`curl_setopt`](http://php.net/curl-setopt).
- Mysqli: opción `MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` usando [`mysqli::options`](http://php.net/mysqli.options).
- Sockets y streams: usando [`socket_set_timeout` y `stream_set_timeout`](http://php.net/stream-set-timeout) (ambas son equivalentes).

**Explicación detallada**

[Como puedes ver en el código fuente de PHP](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/43e283fd6476216ff453514a68c906810740d2b0/Zend/zend_execute_API.c#L1158) cuando se genera el error de tiempo de ejecución excesivo es imposible detener su propagación y detección del script:

```
zend_error_noreturn(E_ERROR, "Maximum execution time of " ZEND_LONG_FMT " second%s exceeded", EG(timeout_seconds), EG(timeout_seconds) == 1 ? "" : "s");
```

La diferencia entre generar un [`zend_error_noreturn`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/beb9295790c32dde5364d8ce03dde7848641c7f1/Zend/zend.c#L1335) y un [`zend_throw_error`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/beb9295790c32dde5364d8ce03dde7848641c7f1/Zend/zend.c#L1347) es que, como puede verse en el código fuente, el primero genera un error que no puede capturarse y, como dije antes, no puede detenerse la finalización del script y, en el segundo caso, genera una excepción que desencadena el proceso de detección de quién la captura.

Se podría pensar que usando [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/set-error-handler) se podría capturar, pero tal y como se explica en la documentación no es así por ser de tipo `E_ERROR`:

> Los siguientes tipos de errores no pueden ser manejados con una
>   función definida por el usuario: **E_ERROR**, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR,
>   E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, y la mayoría de
>   E_STRICT ocasionados en el archivo desde donde se llamó a
>   `set_error_handler()`.

En resumen: **se trata de un ERROR y no una EXCEPCIÓN, por lo que no podrás capturarla**, aunque mediante la ayuda del framework que implementa "trucos" podrás personalizar la vista del error.

Answer (score 2):

Las excepciones en Laravel normalmente son administradas por `App\Exception\Handler.php`. Básicamente ahí debes poner la lógica con la que desees tratar cualquier tipo de excepción.

El método donde deberías agregar tu lógica sobre como administrar dicha excepción es en `render()`:

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof CustomException) {
        return response()->view('errors.custom', [], 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Aunque la descripción dice que es para convertir la excepción en una respuesta HTTP, también es correcto administrarla como desees, no necesariamente convirtiéndola a un código HTTP como 404 o 500.

Comment: Siento dejarte un negativo, pero esto no responde ni soluciona la pregunta planteada.

Comment: Ciertamente, es imposible capturar un error por agotar el tiempo de ejecución. Para cualquier otra excepción tu respuesta es excelente, pero en este caso concreto, es imposible capturar. Lo cual me lleva a preguntar... Por qué es la respuesta aceptada? Ayudó esto al OP realmente?

Comment: Parece que estaba equivocado @Muriano, capturando el evento `shutdown` es posible gestionar un error y convertirlo por software en excepción. En mi respuesta he detallado el proceso que usa symfony (Laravel se basa en Symfony) para hacerlo, pero me parece matar moscas a cañonazos interceptar esa excepción para detectar que se excedió el tiempo de ejecución de un socket, cuando para eso están las funciones de timeout. @Shaz, he retirado mi voto negativo.

Comment: @OscarGarcia, primera noticia. Todos los días se aprende algo. Retirado el negativo.